# Google App Engine PHP Helloworld Example Does Nothing

Tags: php, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I assume I'm making some simple mistake, but I just can't get the Google App Engine PHP SDK (GAE) "helloworld" example to work.

When I attempt to run the example on a Windows XP command line, I get no errors.  The dev appserver is ever started on port 8080. I followed the [GAE PHP SDK "Getting Started" page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/gettingstarted/helloworld) to the letter.  If I mistype the path name, I get an error on that, but that’s it.

I have installed Python 2.7, PHP 5.4 and the GAE PHP SDK 1.8.3. All seem to work independently without error. Testing such…phpinfo() works, the Python interpreter works as well.

I’ve read all of the other questions/answers on this subject on the Stack(here) but nothing has helped.  Here's some details:

My "helloworld" dir (the app.yawl file is there too):

> C:\helloworld\helloworld.php

My Google GAE dir:

> C:\google_appengine

My PHP dir:

> C:\PHP

My Python dir:

> C:\Python27

Here's the dev appserver startup command line I'm using in a Windows XP CMD window:

```
python C:\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path=C:\PHP\php-cgi.exe C:\helloworld\helloworld
```

The dev web server does not start, can't see the listener on default port 8080 in netstat.

Comment: Can you post the actual error message from running dev_appserver?

Answer (score 0):

You said that the `app.yawl` file is present in the helloworld directory.

Its actually `app.yaml` . You may have saved that with incorrect extension. Check it.

The other thing I noticed is in the last command you are pointing to the .php file as `C:\helloworld\helloworld`.

You should actually point to the `APPLICATION_DIRECTORY`, which in your case is just `C:/helloworld/`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  Yes, the real file name in that dir really is "app.yaml", but good catch.  I tried C:\helloworld\ but no change.  The C:\> prompt comes back with no error and nothing else happens.  Here's my current command line: C:\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path=C:\PHP\php-cgi.exe C:\helloworld\